# Java math.pow method, am I printing it incorrectly? (New to java)

Tags: java

Sorry this might be a stupid question but Im trying to learn java and im currently really confused. Im currently learning the math.pow(); method and Im really confused to as what is going on. If i declare an integer called power which is equal to 2 and then use Math.pow(); and raise 2, to the power of 2 and print power i get 2. Am I printing Math.pow incorrectly? Thanks!

```
int power = 2;
Math.pow(2, power);
System.out.println(power);
```

Comment: Try leaning an clarifying about assignment of variables.

Comment: @Sphiinx if below answers answer your problem then kindly [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) one of the answer so that others can refer it in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to assign the result of the `pow` method to the `power` variable if you want it to contain that result:

```
power = Math.pow(2, power);
```

Otherwise the `power` variable remains unchanged.

Answer (score 4):

You can store `returned` result (from `Math.pow()` method) in a variable and then print it.

```
int power = 2;
int result = Math.pow(2, power);
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.pow` is a *function* that returns a value. You are discarding that. Rework to

`int result = Math.pow(2, power);`

Functions that do not modify their input parameters tend to lead to improved program stability. Java is very good at that.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you don't want to store the result, you can use:

```
System.out.println(Math.pow(2, power));
```

It works, because the Math.pow() function returns a double value, and the println function gets it and writes it to your console